# How do I 'initialize' my graphics?

Tags: graphics, draw, shapes, init

My friend has make me a simple JFrame, and I am meant to work on it and develop it. I have encountered a problem within the first 30 mins of having it: it's not drawing the graphics!!

Here is the code that draws the graphics, and the code from the class that brings up the JFrame.

Thanks in advance.

```
GameCanvas.java

/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package danielballtest;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
*
* @author Kris
*/
public class GameCanvas extends Canvas{
Player p;
LinkedList<Stalker> s = new LinkedList<>();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    p.paintItAll(g2d);
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        s.get(i).paintItAll(g2d);
    }
}

public GameCanvas() {
    initComponents();
    repaint();
}

public void initComponents() {
    p = new Player(new Point(50,50));
    s.add(new Stalker(new Point(50,100)));
}

public Point getPlayerPos() {
    return p.getPos();
}
}





MainWindow.java
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package danielballtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
*
* @author Kris
*/
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
static int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
static int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public MainWindow() {
    super("STALKER!!!!!!!!!!");
    GameCanvas canvas = new GameCanvas();
    add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(xSize, ySize);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);      
    canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old AWT `Canvas` class as the base component. This class follows the AWT painting mechanism, where there is no `paintComponent` method and you were supposed to override `paint` to do custom graphics.

Change the base class to `JComponent` and you can use the newer painting mechanism:

```
...
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class GameCanvas extends JComponent {
```

[This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) compares how painting works in AWT and Swing if you want to know more about them.